# MongoDB Service Will Not Start After Initial Setup

Tags: linux, mongodb, fedora

I am running Fedora 20 and installed MongoDB per the [Red Hat installation guide](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/) on the official documentation. I was able to run the `mongod` daemon as a service without error the very first time but when I shut down my machine and came back, the service refused to start due to some failure.

In my log, listed after the successful run, I see this:

```
***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid: No such file or directory
```

If I try starting `mongod` or running `mongod --repair` manually, I get this message in a start up failure:

```
ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
```

This is odd considering that in my config file in `/etc/mongod.conf`, the settings for the database path are as follows:

```
dbpath=/var/lib/mongo
```

Finally, if I run this command:

```
mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo
```

The daemon starts up just fine. However, I am unable to replicate that error free behavior for starting a service.

Can anyone tell me what exactly is wrong and how I can begin running `mongod` as a service?

EDIT

I get this message if I run `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`:

`about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections. forked process: 2702 ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1`

The `/var/run/mongodb` directory did not exist, so I created and assigned it to the mongod user. That did not make much of a difference, unfortunately.

My `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` shows this message:

`[initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating`

Comment: You need to specify the config file to get mongod read it. Try `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`. And for the original question, does the directory `/var/run/mongodb` exist? If not (I assume so), try to create it with permission 666 (or 644 and chown it to the daemon user), then try to restart it?

Comment: `Permission denied` means you screwed permissions up. Try to chown every of the related directory/files back to the mongod user.

Comment: Turns out that `/etc/mongod.conf` was owned by the root. I changed it but still no go on the config.

Comment: So, there're two things to check: 1. `ps aux|grep mongo` make sure there's no mongod instance running. and if not, 2. check the permission for directory `/var/lib/mongo`

Comment: There is not mongod process and `/var/lib/mongo/` has 666 chmod permission.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What worked for me on Fedora 20: we need to create the temp dir on every boot, and that's handled by systemd-tmpfiles. So, create a file /lib/tmpfiles.d/mongodb.conf and put one line in it:

```
d /var/run/mongodb 0755 mongod mongod
```

That seems to handle it on restarts; if you don't want to restart right away, you can execute that with:

```
sudo systemd-tmpfiles --create mongodb.conf
```

(See the man pages for systemd-tmpfiles)

Comment: This has also worked on CentOS 7.2 with MongoDB 3.4. Thank you.

Comment: You are a lifesaver!! I would i could upvote you more worked on centos 7.2

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem, I solved it temporarily, disabling SELinux, rebooted the machine, eliminated mongod.lock:

```
#rm /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock
```

By creating the file /var/run/mongodb/mongo.pid (as mentioned in the configuration file /etc/mongod.conf):

```
#mkdir /var/run/mongodb
#touch /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```

and giving 777 permissions:

```
#chmod 777 /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```

and starting mongo:

```
#service mongod start
```

But the problem persists after restarting the machine. The folder and file disappear.

Comment: That is pretty much what happened to me upon the initial installation. I find it bothersome that disabling SELinux is necessary to get this done. I am sure this is a permission issue but cannot pinpoint the origin given that every relevant file/folder is chown to mongod.

Comment: i have the same problem on openSuse 13.1 , @Pori - how did you fix that problem? didn't quite understand the SELinux thing...

Comment: Please can you see https://serverfault.com/questions/1026257/after-delete-cache-files-bug-in-permissions-for-run Mr. @Deoxyseia

Answer (score 7):

I've spent a while looking into this, and it appears as if the pid folder and file permissions don't work with the default daemon.

The simplest solution I've come across is disable the pid file by just putting a # in front of the line in the config file.

```
vi /etc/mongod.conf
```

find the line that says pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid and change it accordingly.

```
# pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```

For information on what commenting it out does check here.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#processManagement.pidFilePath

Answer (score 6):

If you’re starting mongod as a service using:

> sudo service mongod start

Make sure the directories defined for logpath, dbpath, and pidfilepath in your mongod.conf exist and are owned by mongod:mongod.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in Ubuntu:

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:27017) 
sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo rm -f /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock
sudo rm -f /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
sudo mkdir -p  /var/run/mongodb/
sudo touch /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
sudo chown -R  mongodb:mongodb /var/run/mongodb/
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
sudo service mongod start
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem running mongodb 3.0.4 on OpenSuse 13.2, and I found that the mongod directory under /var/run was missing.  If I created the directory manually it would disappear after a reboot.

I solved it by adding the following lines to my /etc/init.d/mongod startup script:

```
mkdir -p /var/run/mongod  
chown $MONGO_USER:$MONGO_GROUP /var/run/mongod
```

Comment: Actually, while this works, Vitalie's answer looks to be the correct procedure.

Answer (score 0):

We need to create the **temp dir** location of pidfile `/var/run/mongodb` that's handled by systemd-tmpfiles. So, create a file /lib/tmpfiles.d/mongodb.conf as root:

> lnx#> sudo su
>   lnx#> cd /lib/tmpfiles.d
>   lnx#> echo “d /var/run/mongodb 0755 mongod mongod” > mongodb.conf

Then reboot or run this command to activate that temp directory:

> lnx#>sudo systemd-tmpfiles --create mongodb.conf

Start mongod service:

> lnx#> sudo systemctl start mongod.service

**Bibliography:** [Fedora And Mongodb · l33tsource](http://l33tsource.com/blog/2013/11/30/Fedora-and-MongoDB/)

Answer (score 0):

i met the same issue,when i modify my mongod.conf as follow and problem resolved~

```
port=27017
dbpath=/usr/local/mongodb/data/db/
logpath=/usr/local/mongodb/logs
fork = true
```

tips: logpath is the logfile not a folder.

Answer (score 0):

I just experience a similar problem on ubuntu. Encountered nearly every ERROR tips, like

```
child process failed, exited with error number 1
```

or`child process failed, exited with error number 100`

or `[signalProcessingThread] got signal 2 (Interrupt: 2), will terminate after current cmd ends`

For many times I remove the Mongodb and try to install again, but the problem remains....

Finally I came to this way:
Backup your data first, then remove Mongodb with

```
#sudo apk-get autoremove mongodb-org
```

Find out all the files related with mongodb:

```
/#find -name mongo*
```

Delete them all with "rm" or "rmdir", including the packages in the /var/cache/... and everthing.

Then repeat the installation as the first time you did :

```
#echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
#sudo apt-get update
#sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

It will run again.

Answer (score 0):

Comment below the line from your "mongo.conf" file.

**pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid**

Answer (score 0):

**Following commands solved for cent os**

*ERROR*:

```
 service mongod status
 Error starting mongod. /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid exists
```

*FIXED BY:*

```
   rm /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock
   chown -R mongod:mongod /var/log/mongodb/
   chown -R mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb/
   chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongo/
   chmod 777 /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid

   mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mongodb
sudo mkdir /var/log/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
```

Comment: Your answer contains code without explanation. It's better to include details about *how* your answer answers the question.